# Foreground service dying after few hours

Tags: c#, xamarin

**Issue**

I have problem with my foreground service. When I start the application, service started successfully. But after a few hours, for an unknown reason, service dies. (And a notification is removed from top bar in mobile).

I tested it on multiple mobile devices and this problem is present everywhere, even when battery saver is off.

**Code**

My service:

```
    [Service]
    public class PService : Service
    {

        const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }


        [Obsolete]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("my_service_urgent", "My Channel", NotificationImportance.None);
            chan.EnableVibration(false);
            chan.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Secret;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);

            var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "my_service_urgent")
            .SetContentTitle("title")
            .SetContentText("text")
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetChannelId("my_service_urgent")
            .Build();

            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            Device.StartTimer(seconds, () =>
            {


            Root r = new Root();

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(***PRIVATE***);
            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user_data";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DateTime user = DateTime.Now;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetString(0) == Preferences.Get("GUID", "ERROR"))
                {

                    user = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[1].ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    r.ID = reader.GetString(2);
                }
            }

            async void LoadCallLog()
            {
                var Logg = DependencyService.Get<ICallLog>().GetCallLogs();

                r.calls = (List<CallLogModel>)Logg;

                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    await client.PostAsync("https://webhook.site/dd7cd0f8-6bd8-4e9f-961d-6b105e1dc7eb", new StringContent(serialized));
                }
            }

            if (user.ToString("HH:mm") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))
            {
                LoadCallLog();
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }

                return true;
            });

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
        }
    }
```

Does someone have idea what is wrong?

Comment: Look at the `logcat` output to determine why, either your app is crashing or the OS is terminating it (ANR, etc...) (and since you are using a `Service` subclass, you should not `Thread.Sleep` as that will block the UI thread, use Task.Delay or another thread)

Comment: Seconding `Thread.Sleep` being evil. Who keeps teaching this?

Comment: Well, you're far from alone.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede nobody, just my specialty ;D Do you have idea how I can do this better?

Comment: As @SushiHangover suggested, `Task.Delay`. This isn't just good practice, it may actually solve your problem. The general idea is 1) use the thread pool, it's clever and effficient; and 2) you don't own the thread pool threads, so never block them.

Comment: I have this error: `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
  Message=A task was canceled.`

Comment: @RitchyCZE You could try to restart the service in `OnSleep` event.

Comment: @SushiHangover answer is working.

Comment: @RitchyCZE Have you try to restart the service in OnSleep event?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT No.